# FreeBSD: system is sending mail for any user to an external smtp - why?

Tags: email, freebsd, sendmail

There is a problem with one of my jails. All Jails sending their mails for root to root, except one jail (nginx). This jail sends mails to `root@jailname.domain.tld`. My Postfix is configured to accept those mails but I don't find the reason why only this jail is sending to the relay. (Strange thing: If I send a mail from jail nginx the mail will be signed with DKIM. If I use `~./forward` in another jail than nginx to reach my Postfix, the mail will not be DKIM-signed.) 
Using `~/.forward` in the jail nginx will be ignored.

The jail is sending every mail to the external relay (even for users that don't exist!)

In all Jails I set `sendmail_enable=NO` and sendmail isn't running. Also `pkg info` don't list any 3rd-party mailer.

Test from this Jail (Jailname: nginx):

```
mail -v root
Subject: test
test
.
EOT
root... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 mail.domain.tld ESMTP TheTardis
>>> EHLO nginx.domain.tld
250-mail.domain.tld
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 52428800
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 SMTPUTF8
>>> STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>>> EHLO nginx.domain.tld
250-mail.domain.tld
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 52428800
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 SMTPUTF8
>>> MAIL From: SIZE=29
250 2.1.0 Ok
>>> RCPT To:
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 Ok
354 End data with .
>>> .
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 52FAC2BDC6E8
root... Sent (Ok: queued as 52FAC2BDC6E8)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Test from any other Jail:

```
# mail -v root
Subject: test
test
.
EOT
root... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 mysql.domain.tld ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2; Tue, 7 May 2019 17:05:05 +0200 (CEST)
>>> EHLO mysql.domain.tld
250-mysql.domain.tld Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
>>> EHLO mysql.domain.tld
250-mysql.domain.tld Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> MAIL From: SIZE=29
250 2.1.0 ... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 ... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
250 2.0.0 x47F55hU031641 Message accepted for delivery
root... Sent (x47F55hU031641 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 mysql.domain.tld closing connection
```

So, you see that the jail nginx is relaying his mails to the mailserver while other jails don't.
I don't know why.
I tryed several ideas to find the cause of relaying:

`# cat ~/.forward
cat: /root/.forward: No such file or directory`

`# cat ~/.mailrc
cat: /root/.mailrc: No such file or directory`

`# mail -d root` say: `user = root, homedir = /root` `Sendmail arguments: "send-mail" "-i" "root"`

`/etc/mail/` is untouched. The timestamps points to the time, the jail was build. Also there is no `.mc`-file except the initially existend `freebsd.mc` and `freebsd.submit.mc`. Because of this there is also no special directive in `/etc/mail/aliases`.

The directive to relay mails to the external mailserver must come from outside `/etc/mail` but I don't have any clues where to search any more...

Any ideas?

edit1: I did `grep -rl 10.23.102.251 /` (the mailserver-IP) and `grep -rl mail.domain.tld /` last night. Each ran for about four hours and found nothing.

edit2: sendmail is served by:

```
    # cat /etc/mail/mailer.conf

    # $FreeBSD: releng/11.1/etc/mail/mailer.conf 93858 2002-04-05 04:25:14Z gshapiro $
    #
    # Execute the "real" sendmail program, named /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
    #
    sendmail        /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
    send-mail       /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
    mailq           /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
    newaliases      /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
    hoststat        /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
    purgestat       /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple `grep -ir mail.domain.tld /etc` or even `grep -ir mail.domain.tld /`?

Comment: Thx. I did, see edit1 in answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into */etc/mail/mailer.conf* what utility is serving *sendmail* and find out which package provides *sendmail*. In default installation the command

```
# pkg_which /usr/libexec/sendmail/sendmail
```

shows nothing and it will be necessary to review the configuration of *Sendmail*. This is something that really nobody wants and frequent practice is to replace *Sendmail* with *Postfix*. See details in [28.4. Changing the Mail Transfer Agent](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/mail-changingmta.html). In this case /etc/mail/mailer.conf looks like

```
sendmail        /usr/local/sbin/sendmail
send-mail       /usr/local/sbin/sendmail
mailq           /usr/local/sbin/sendmail
newaliases      /usr/local/sbin/sendmail
```

and *pkg_which* would report for example

```
# pkg_which /usr/local/sbin/sendmail
postfix-sasl-3.3.1_1,1
```

But probably the best practice [to send mail through a relay](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/outgoing-only.html) is mail/ssmtp. In this case /etc/mail/mailer.conf looks like

```
sendmail        /usr/local/sbin/ssmtp
send-mail       /usr/local/sbin/ssmtp
mailq           /usr/local/sbin/ssmtp
newaliases      /usr/local/sbin/ssmtp
hoststat        /usr/bin/true
purgestat       /usr/bin/true
```

and *pkg_which* would report for example

```
# pkg_which /usr/local/sbin/ssmtp
ssmtp-2.64_3
```

You may try to reconfigure current MTA, but if you can change it I'd recommend using *mail/ssmtp* or *mail/postfix* if a more complex configuration is needed.